# How do I include swagger-docs in a controller that inherits from a different base controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I'm using [swagger-docs](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs) to add documentation to an API, and my configuration looks like this:

```
Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
  "1.0" => {
    :api_file_path => "public/",
    :base_path => "http://localhost:3000",
    :clean_directory => true,
    :base_api_controller => ActionController::API,
    :attributes => {
      :info => {
        "title" => "Test",
        "description" => "Test",
        "contact" => "contact@example.com",
        "license" => "MIT",
        "licenseUrl" => "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This works ok for controllers that inherit from `ActionController::API`, but how do I include the DSL methods when a controller inherits from a different base controller? For example, when using the `knock` gem for authentication:

```
class Users::AuthenticationController < Knock::AuthTokenController
  swagger_controller :login, "Request a new JWT to issue authenticated requests"

  swagger_api :create do
    summary "Generates a JWT to be used for authenticated requests"
    param :email, "auth[email]", :string, :required, "Email for authentication"
    param :password, "auth[password]", :string, :required, "Password for authentication"
    response :created
    response :not_found, "Credentials specified were wrong"
  end

  def entity_class
    User
  end
end
```

This code returns the following error:

```
undefined method `swagger_controller' for Users::AuthenticationController:Class
```

I tried including the methods using:

```
include Swagger::Docs::ImpotentMethods
```

But this didn't work, even though it removed the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was really dumb and I hope it saves time to someone in the future:

`include Swagger::Docs::ImpotentMethods` is just an empty implementation of the methods, just as the name says.

Include the methods like this instead and it should be all working properly:

```
class Users::AuthenticationController < Knock::AuthTokenController
  include Swagger::Docs::Methods
end
```